# View button with if else statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, grid, response.redirect

I have a gridview and I want to add a button 'VIEW' which redirects to the (`Customers.aspx?CustomerID=`) page. Every customer has a ID and each ID is associated with a report.  I don't want the ID to show up in my gridview and I want it to be hidden.
Also, I want this button to show up only if the USER is an "Admin" or a "Salesperson" category. I s there a way i can bind my CustomerID to a UserCategory to generate reports for each ID separately.

I tried looking at some other posts as well but my button doesn't redirect for some reason. 
Can someone please help me figure out what i am doing wrong here or if i am missing something. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

```
    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Button ID="btnView" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Select" Text="VIEW"  />
              </ItemTemplate>
              <ControlStyle CssClass="button" />
           </asp:TemplateField>



 protected void btnView(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)button.NamingContainer;
    Label lblCustomerID = (Label)row.FindControl("lblCustomerID");

    txtHFUserCategory.Value = Session["UserCategoryPC"].ToString();
    String strUserCat = MTProcs.GetSingleDatabaseResult("SELECT tblUsers.UserCategoryID FROM tblUsers WHERE UserID = " + txtHFUserID.Value);
    if (strUserCat == "4" || strUserCat == "12")
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "window.open(Customers.aspx?CustomerID=" + lblLeadID.Text + "');", true);

    }
}
```

Comment: how is user and customer tables are linked in database ?

Comment: You will need to join those two tables. Otherwise, it won't be efficient to query sub table for every row.

Comment: Do you want the `<asp:Button>` to exist IN the GridView? (i.e. within a cell of a column) or do you want it to just be on the page somewhere? The answer will determine whether you need to use a `_RowDataBound()` event handler on the GridView, or really just need an if-then on the page to show or hide the button.

Comment: Also, I'm wondering now if the question has to do with confusion on how to add the button or if it's more just you are stuck on how to do a join with a query... If it's the latter, you'll need to have an FK into the `CATEGORY` table's `ID` (I'm assuming which is a PK) from the `CUSTOMER` table and then do a simple join in query that selects all customer information when the Customer.<NEW_FK_INTO_CATEGORY_PK> == Category.ID

Comment: @bradykey Yes the button needs to exist inside the gridview and only fire if the user category is admin or salesperson. I am confused as to what is a simpler way of doing it and whether if else statement could be used rather than creating a FK in the database?

Comment: @ISHIDA Actually there is no direct relation between those 2 tables.

Comment: @facebook-10153603764680056 @ISHIDA welp, there's your issue. How are you ever storing the `Category` of a `Customer`? If there is no relation between the two, you'd never be able to query and even ask the question, "Is this Customer an Admin or a Salesperson?"

Comment: Oops, I realize I was mistaking `CATEGORY` with `USER` -- my fault. Still, I don't see how you can get by without relating `CUSTOMER` and `USER`, unless I'm misunderstanding the line "But, the data it should reflects is in Customer table. I am confused as to how to code this because I want the button which depends on one table but the data is coming from a different table." What is "it"?

Comment: @bradykey That is the challenge here.

Comment: @facebook-10153603764680056 if they are not connected how exactly are you going to get the data ?

Comment: are you saying that whether the button is visible depends on who the current session user is, and what their Category value is in the user table? And then you also want one button for each row in the gridview, right? And each row is a different customer? So the button takes you to the page for that customer, and you also don't know how to make each button know which customer it relates to? I think there are two slightly separate issues here.

Comment: @ADyson yes you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do it with simply adding visible property in your button
like

```
<asp:button ID="yourBtnID" runat="server" Text="WotEver" visible='<%# Convert.toInt(Eval("admin"))==1 && Convert.toInt(Eval("SALESPERSON"))==1 %>'/>
```